# Mixamo + Wiggle bone

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, parent, pose-mode

When I add bones to my mixamo armature (which may not be the problem) the mesh of the body either flies of or sinks to the ground when I add the automatic weights.

What I am trying to do is add wiggle bones to the buttocks area. I have been trying to conquer this for a month but to no avail. Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

In edit mode the whole character mesh and bones included starts on the floor,  could this be the problem?

Comment: Hello, please [edit] your question and add images that help to describe your problem visually for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using on my character's hair sinking or moving out of position. Did't work out when I try changing the parent's bone. I solved it by turning Amplitude Rotation to 0, 10 will make it sink. Hope this will help.